# Is Althusser's Marxism a degenerating research program?

Tags: marx, marxism

> His essay "Marxism and Humanism" is a strong statement of
>   anti-humanism in Marxist theory, condemning ideas like "human
>   potential" and "species-being", which are often put forth by Marxists,
>   as outgrowths of a bourgeois ideology of "humanity".

And, also from wikipedia

> For Althusser, the humanism of Marx's early writings—influenced by
>   Hegel and Feuerbach—is fundamentally incongruous with the
>   "scientific", structure-concerned theory found in Marx's mature works
>   such as Das Kapital.

Does this later, scientific, Marxism really make sense, given the relative obscurity of Marxist ideas?

Seems to me that it's only in a blend of the so called "humanist" and "scientific" Marx, that we can say that Marx's communism may be realisable, as that would rely on different forms of argument, and observation -- is the working class still a potential catalyst for revolutionary change in humanistic terms.

Comment: Is the question whether Althussers reworking make prior or other interpretations less "realisable"? Or are you looking to make sense of his project?

Comment: You seem to be applying [Lacatos's falsificationist label](http://www.loyno.edu/~folse/Lakatos.html) to something that does not  come even close to being a research programme (in his sense) in the first place. The use of "scientific" as applied to either early or late Marx can only be read metaphorically.

Comment: @Conifold i would be more sympathetic to it bineg a metaphor if popper hadn't had used his flasification principle to argue it was pseudo science

Comment: But that is my point. To be a degenerating research program Marxism would have to be a (scientific) research program first, which, according to both Popper and Lakatos, it isn't.

Comment: @Conifold Could you describe in what sense works like Die Grundrisse and Das Kapital do not fit the definition of a research program?

Comment: @anon Althusser's focus on the latter Marx and his methological interest in structuralism was largely to distinguish work from other Marxists contemporary to him and historical that lacked the level of thorough criticality and rigor he felt was needed in the discourse of the 1960's. It perhaps helps to look at it like you're a philosopher who takes political struggle seriously but you're dealing with peers who dumb down Marx's approach and his work and who don't always meet standards of intellectual seriousness and precision. It was a way of challenging them to rise to the occasion.

Comment: @ClearMountainWay Lakatos attaches specialized meaning to the term related to testability, not the loose colloquial one, you can look under the link in my comment. If I recall correctly, Friedman's monetarism does not meet his requirements either. Previous version of your comment indicated that even Marx himself did not see his work as "scientific" in the usual objectivist sense, "*The philosophers have only interpreted the world, in various ways; the point is to change it*" is one reason why.

Comment: @Conifold yeah I deleted the previous comment because I forgot that Engels's writing make reference to things like "scientific socialism" which to me is an unfortunate phrasing because he's never even describing a science in the book, unless a "materialist history" and "materialist dialectics" is considered science. It's a methodology certainly.. For that reason I wanted to refresh my memory of what criteria is used for distinguishing a science from non-scientific methods of critique and analysis.

Comment: @Conifold your 1st sentence would answer the question; it's only your 2nd sentence that I challenged, which is why I asked the question. does althusser mean to use the term metaphorically?

Comment: thought I just googled and it *seems* less obvious than you claim that marxism was not a research programme @Conifold

Comment: It appears that [Lakatos was agnostic on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imre_Lakatos#cite_note-17) beyond Soviet Marxism. Burawoy, using his framework, even argues that some [Marxism is a progressive research program](http://burawoy.berkeley.edu/Marxism/Marxism%20As%20Science.pdf). But if your question is whether Althusser considers Marxism (literally) scientific that doesn't come through in the OP at all.

Comment: @Conifold well it's an implicit claim (that he does) which welcomes correction. Apologies, really, if that's poor question asking practice